# How to use angularjs to change the values of another select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ui-select

I have two Web API's that I am calling. Each value in the first api Type has an `ID` that needs to be used to **filter** the second api which is Category. The `JSON` is below:

```
// Types
[{"ID":1,"Text":"Hardware","Description":"Hardware"}, 
 {"ID":2,"Text":"Software,"Description":"Software"}"}];

// Categories
[{"ID":1,"TypeID":1,"ParentID":0,"Name":"Printing"}, 
 {"ID":2,"TypeID":1,"ParentID":1,"Name":"Toner"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to store selectedTypeID that will be used to filter another array, and than you can call [Angular $filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in your second array.

Sintax:

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

e.g:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.categories, {TypeID: $scope.selectedTypeID}, comparator)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When i tried angular $filter it pretty much sorted the information I needed to the top but did not create a select with only those values.

Comment: Hmmm, this $filter return to you an array with filtered values only, have you tried to set this array to your select values ?

Comment: Would I pass the value from Type into my controller and run another function to check that ID against the array of Category and pass that array to the to the select?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking this: *How can I dynamically populate a `select` input based on the selection in another `select` input?

I think you can go two ways. If there is not much total data (like with `Categories`), you could use a `filter` on the second set of data. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter#!

You can do this in the HTML or in the controller!

```
<!-- HTML Page -->
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="value in values | filter..." value=value>
</select>

// controller.js
values = ($filter('filter')(result.Values, {Id: $routeParams.Id}));
```

If there is lots of data to filter, consider delaying your call to the `Category` API until a `Type` is selected.

Without seeing the controller/HTML and whatnot, it's hard to give a specific answer, but I think this will get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for responding. In the Types select I put an ng-change and called a function from my controller that set that value to $scope.ID and I placed that on the filter for the Categories select. Is this along the lines of what your trying to do in the example? What this did was sort the values according to that ID but the other values were still there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.countries = CustomerService.getCountry();

$scope.getCountryStates = function(){
    $scope.sates = CustomerService.getCountryState($scope.customer.Country);
    $scope.cities =[];
};

<select ng-model="customer.State" 
    ng-options="x.Id as x.state for x in sates"
    ng-change = "getStateCities()"
    class="form-control"
    ng-required="true"
    id="state">
    <option value="">-- Choose State --</option>
</select> 

<select  ng-model="customer.City" 
  ng-options="x.Id as x.city for x in cities"
    class="form-control" 
    ng-required="true"
    id="city">
    <option value="">-- Choose City --</option>
</select>
```

[Check complete code with demo](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1189/angularjs-cascading-dropdown-select-with-demo)